# Finish jQuery script - Rewrite href

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, replace

I have a jQuery script that is reading from a list, and the anchor link from the list replaces the image class and the href link.
Currently, the image works perfect, but the links are nearly there!! I am unsure as to how to add '.html' on the end.

I have the following:

```
$('ul[class="address-list"] li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cl = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
    $('.map-wrapper').removeClass().addClass('map-wrapper '+cl);
    var _href = $("a.map-link").attr("href").replace('#','');
    $("a.map-link").attr("href", '/img/map/' +cl);
    return false; // Prevent default behaviour
```

This outputs a link as the following...
/img/map/link-class

HOWEVER, I am after /img/map/link-class.html
I have a series of html files for each class that has a short redirect code within to refer to the correct page.
The jQuery link in questions I believe is this..

```
$("a.map-link").attr("href", '/img/map/' +cl);
```

I am unsure as to how to add a '.html' after the +cl

Any help?

Comment: What are the `_href` and `cl` variables used for? They don't seem to be used anywhere prior to the `return`, after which they can't be used (since the function's already returned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("a.map-link").attr("href", '/img/map/' + cl + '.html');
```

Comment: Ahh.. how easy and sweet it is! Sorry for the newbie-ness! I am new to scripts.. THANK YOU! Learning every day!